# Creating and tracking model instance for each user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i am working on this simple quiz app, and i think i messed my model all up.
The original objective is to have a quiz taker model, quiz categories, levels and a list of questions under each. However, am worn out on how to structure the model to enable each user have an instance of the quiz, levels and questions in order to keep track of the players progress.

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


# QUIZ CLASS MODEL
class Quiz(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="quiz name")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category',]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category}"


#  LEVEL CLASS MODEL
class Level(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    DIFFICULTY = [
        (("level1"),("level1")), (("level2"),("level2")), (("level3"),("level3")), (("level4"),("level4")), (("level5"),("level5")),
         (("level6"),("level6")), (("level7"),("level7")), (("level8"),("level8")), (("level9"),("level9")), (("level10"),("level10")),
         (("bonus"),("bonus"))
         ]
    levels = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DIFFICULTY)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="check if category level has been completed")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.levels



# QUESTION CLASS MODELS
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    is_answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question


# ANSWER CLASS MODEL
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice



# QUIZ TAKER MODEL
class QuizTaker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    token = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_quiztaker(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        QuizTaker.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_quiztaker(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    try:
        if created == False:
            instance.quiztaker.save()
    except:
        QuizTaker.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**ADMIN.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question, QuizTaker, Quiz, Answer, Level


# Register your models here.
# admin.site.register(Question)
class answeinline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer
    min_num = 4
    max_num = 4

class levelinline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Level
    min_num = 10
    max_num = 11


@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['question', 'quiz', 'is_answered']
    inlines = [answeinline]

@admin.register(Quiz)
class QuizAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [levelinline]

admin.site.register(QuizTaker)
```

Comment: Are you facing schema design issue?

Comment: Don't know if I'd say schema issue. My model just kinda seems wrong for the expected job.